# Consumer not authorized to access self

Tags: magento2, rest-api, access, accessibility

I am following a Magento tutorial and I get stuck at this step https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-quote.html
So I managed to create user, but I cannot make a shoppingcart. I have requested the bearer token and pass it to `/rest/all/V1/carts/mine/` But all I get back is:

```
{
    "message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "self"
    }
}
```

I am able to create a user by passing the admin bearer token, but that is not ideal for me. The easiest way for me seems that the user can create a shoppingcart with it's own credentials.

So is there a setting I can change? I am aware of the **Allow Anonymous Guest Access** setting, but since I made an export of my config I cannot edit this value. So is there a way to edit that value throught the `config.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **First Login in Magento2 Using Api**

**Api Url** : https://xyz/rest/V1/integration/customer/token 
**Token**   : dcx8leo2oquwv6wjmkpxsl3nnzg2n5s0(#BEARER_TOKEN) 
**Method**  : Post
**Body**  : {
"username": "dev-test@example.com",
"password": "Test@123456789"
}
**Response**: "82ag2sdf7jay1ofsja0iskk59joaas28"(#CUSTOMER_ACCESS_TOKEN)

**Note** :  With login API we will get Customer Token for ex.  82ag2sdf7jay1ofsja0iskk59joaas28 and this will be pass in the next API.

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

**Api Url** : https://xyz/rest/V1/carts/mine/  
**Token**   : 82ag2sdf7jay1ofsja0iskk59joaas28(#CUSTOMER_ACCESS_TOKEN)(Previous Api Reponse)

**Now you will get proper response.**

Comment: These are the exact steps I did in the link I attached in my questions. Still getting the same error message

Comment: Api url is wrong correct is : http://xyz/rest/V1/carts/mine

Comment: That was it, I was requesting it with the /all/ path parameter to specify the store. Just out of curiosity do you know where I need to specify the store parameter?